# Rstan not running without internet connection on mac

Tags: r, curl, rstan

When rstan starts to compile a model, and I'm not connected to the internet, it halts and gives me a curl related error. I assume this is because rstan depends in some way on shinystan. Error below:

Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to api.ipify.org:443

Another odd thing about this is that this only happens on my mac laptop; it doesn't happen on my windows desktop when it isn't connected to the internet. This is a recent issue so I think it is related to an update to rstan, curl, or shinystan.

Thanks for your help!

Zach

Comment: The GitHub repo for RStan is the best place to file issues: https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan

Comment: Thanks for replying. Will move my comment there.